# Apache/PHP: Any way to retrieve the ServerName setting via PHP

Tags: php, apache, apache2, virtualhost

I have an Apache virtual host that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName host1.example.com
    ServerAlias host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/web/host1.example.com/pub
</VirtualHost>
```

I have the following file:

```
/srv/web/host1.example.com/pub/test.php
```

I am requesting the following URL (notice that I am using the `ServerAlias`, not the `ServerName`:

```
http://host2.example.com/test.php
```

I'd like to have `test.php` output the `ServerName` variable somehow (`host1.example.com`). Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, when you access a VirtualHost through the alias, there is no trace of the original 
`SERVER_NAME` in any of the `$_SERVER` variables.

The only idea that comes to mind is setting an environment variable:

```
SetEnv MY_HOST host1.example.com
```

this should set the value of `$_SERVER["MY_HOST"]` to the correct host name. No guarantees though, I have never tried this in practice.

Comment: Man, I submitted my answer and got a human verification captcha which slowed me down. Otherwise I would beat ya. +1

Comment: Based on the example I provided above, `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` contains `host2.example.com`, not `host1.example.com`.

Comment: @matt ah, sorry, overread that. Hmmm, in that case you may be stuck with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` but that is to be handled with care because it can be freely set by the client. Do a `print_r($_SERVER);` to see whether the Alias is in any other variable in this constellation, it may be

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` contains `host2.example.com`, not `host1.example.com`. The string `host1.example.com` is not in `$_SERVER` at all.

Comment: @matt hmmm, I see. Tricky. In that case, the only idea that comes to mind is adding a `SetEnv MY_HOST host1.example.com`. It should set a `MY_HOST`  environment variable that you should be able to fetch from `$_SERVER`. Try it - no guarantees though, have never tried this.

Comment: @Pekka Thanks for your input. If you add that as an answer, I'll be able to mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

With our webhost, the default admin email is `webmaster@<virtual-hostname>`. Thanks to this, I can get the virtuel host name through

```
$virtualhostname = substr($_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN'], strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN'], '@') + 1);
```