# ServerName in vhost not set in php $_SERVER variable?

Tags: php, apache

The ServerName is set in the virtual host but when I reference `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` I get whatever is set in the request header.

I was playing around with spoofing it and whatever I set the Host request header to that's what gets populated in the server variable.

I thought it should take whatever is in the vhost and another variable like `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` should have the request header value.

I would expect some dummy value gets set if the vhost isn't working properly and not just using the request header.

Is there any apache config settings I should look into? What could cause this to be happening on the server?

The reason I want to rely on the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is for security and reliability so users' can't spoof it, so we are the ones who set it and key off it during scripting.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your HTTPd server ? Nginx ? Apache ?

Comment: @KevinLabécot apache tagged. OP, show us what you tried at the moment

Comment: @kmsdev Oops... Sorry. Anyway, I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any apache config settings I should be looking into

I found an interesting [comment](http://www.php.net//manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net//manual/) which implies that to have the actual apache ServerName value is to make sure that the `UseCanonicalName` apache directory is turned On.

> When using the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] variable in an apache virtual host setup with a ServerAlias directive, be sure to check the UseCanonicalName apache directive.  If it is On, this variable will always have the apache ServerName value.  If it is Off, it will have the value given by the headers sent by the browser.

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but probably worth checking into.

**Edit**

(Probably) More relevant to the question: I found [someone](https://www.mail-archive.com/php-general@lists.php.net/msg140689.html) who ran into a similar problem as you:

> I am using the variable $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] inside a function [...] But we can modify the value of $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] before calling the function check_servname(). And I am looking for a the right server name not for a server name which may have been changed before calling check_servername:

One solution is to define a superglobal variable (yeah... nasty but...) right at startup which cannot be modified, so by referencing the superglobal variable you could be sure to be getting the correct value.

So using something like

```
define ( 'SERVER_NAME' , $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
```

right in the beginning should fix your problem, by referencing `SERVER_NAME` instead of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`. Give it a try.

Comment: UseCanonicalName was the issue, it wasn't set correctly in the httpd.conf so server name was populated by the request variables.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SERVER_NAME is not set when you access a website via an alias.

See explaination (and answer) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4834148/911718